# Apache on Pi won't display images

Tags: pi-3, image, php, apache-httpd

I'm trying to display images on the Apache server created on Pi.

PHP Code:

```
$files = glob("/var/www/html/Images");
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i];
    echo '<img src="'.$num.'" alt="random image">'."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}
```

Instead of the image I get this:

[image]

I have provided all the permissions, but it doesn't work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: and what do the apache log say?

Comment: Have you tried viewing the source? Could you [edit] in the source code displayed in the browser? You can view the source by right clicking and selecting 'View Page Source' or equivalent in most browsers.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few errors here.

```php
$files = glob("/var/www/html/Images");
```

This line doesn't make a lot of sense as written. [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) returns an array matching the glob pattern (the sort of pattern you use in your terminal, e.g. `/var/www/html/Images/*.jpg`). Your code doesn't get an array of images, as you're expecting here.

```php
$num = $files[$i];
echo '<img src="'.$num.'" alt="random image">'."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```

You're using the full *local* file path, so even with the glob being correct, you'd be getting output like so:

```html
<img src="/var/www/html/Images/foo.jpg" alt="random image">
```

Clearly, you don't want the `/var/www/html` bit, because that path isn't accessible to browsers. You probably want to translate that to the URL path, as hosted by Apache. There are some suggestions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1240462/6650102) how to handle that, which you might like to review. One of the suggestions is:

```php
$num = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $num)
```

This should technically resolve the issue, as long as you sort out the glob. Bear in mind this **isn't terribly secure or good practice**, though, but it does address your immediate problem.